# Message writer of well meaning but unnaceptable edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, edits

I am not sure how to best react to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039736/tashuhka). They have been making a very large number of edits on the review queue which are correct and mostly improve the post, but are mostly extremely minor. As such, I have been accepting a few, but flagging many of them as too minor.

However my issue is this, there appears to be no clear way to leave a message to an editor after rejecting their edit from the review queue. The reason I bring up this specific user is that it appears to me they are clearly well meaning, trying to improve posts and feel bad just rejecting loads of their edits without explanation.

It would be much more helpful if there were a way to leave them some kind of message after the rejection in a similar way to the low-quality post queue to explain to them politely the problem with their edit(s), so they can avoid it in future before just receiving an edit ban.

So my question is somewhat two-fold. Firstly, how should I in the current system deal with a well-meaning but problematic editor like the one above and two? Would there be a possibility of allowing contact somehow with a user whose edit you reject to give them some advice?

Comment: You could ping them using @ from any post where they are in the revision history and do things that way.

Comment: Note that in the current system "too minor" is no longer a valid reason for rejection of an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `@` contact the user in any post where he is in the revision history. I do it too when I see such behaviour and leave a nice comment like

> @tashuhkat: Thanks for improving posts. But please make only substantial edits. At least 3 people need to review your changes before they get approved. That takes time of the reviewers. Make it worth it and leave minor edits to the users having enough rep to edit without needing approval. Thanks.

I tend to get really good reactions on that.

To your other question: AFAIK If someone keeps making minor edits he can get a temporary edit ban. But in reality often minor edits still get approved and too less people mark them as too minor.

Comment: Thanks, I had not noticed that ability. That helps greatly, I had not realized one could reply to an edit as such.

Comment: `s/substancial/substantial/` :)

Comment: I tried to do this because I had the same problem but couldn't find wherever it is that I can contact the original editor. Is there a screenshot available, or could someone please describe where this is?

Comment: @JenB: Just do what I just did. Comment on the post you have something to say about and add the username with an @ to the comment. If the user had something to do with the port - he will be notified.