# Have ability to message edit proposers when reviewing their edits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

Related to [Message writer of well meaning but unnaceptable edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268832/message-writer-of-well-meaning-but-unnaceptable-edits) Instead of putting a public comment on the question, it would be great to be able to privately message a <2000 rep user who has proposed edits with a message like 'Thank you for improving this post, but please make sure you do all the edits required'.

Comment: a fantastic idea. In fact, with enough rank, shouldn't I be able to go to your profile page and send a direct message, without having to go to a recent comment of theirs, on an extraneous post, and alert them that way? Which is how it is currently done, unless I am missing the obvious

Comment: But that can be done with the review rejection already. The only thing that might be missing is the active inbox notification of a rejected edit.

Comment: There's been lots of requests for more general IM features, but have all been rejected - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user. I am hoping that limiting the suggestion to the edit review process might overcome these objections

Comment: @rene I don't want to reject an edit that is correct but incomplete, that seems unfair when the editor is well meaning. I do them as 'Improve edit' and there's no message system available then. The goal is to educate about SO policy.

Comment: If you improve it is obviously good enough, why bother stalking the user. If you think the user should have edited in a better way, reject the edit. This sounds as a feature that is optimizing for a corner-case where a supported feature already exist. I don't mind being unfair and if those editors don't keep an eye on their suggest-edits I doubt if they are open for the educational part of getting the policy explained....

Comment: I have recently got a few correct tag edits with perhaps capitalisation, but ignoring other problems. Probably part of a reputation hunt since the same user will have several edits in the queue, but ultimately they are fixing things so okay. If they do 5-10 minor edits that are all a little incomplete and all robo-accepted, how are they going to learn? I have been following the suggestion in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268832/message-writer-of-well-meaning-but-unnaceptable-edits, but this involves leaving a public and irrelevant comment on the original question being edited.

Comment: the fact is they don't want it fixed. A broken system, but deemed good enough. Ok, a flawed system, but good enough.

Comment: I answered a similar question where the issue of leaving a noise comment on the original post came up. My comment then is relevant here as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305972/pointless-edits-how-to-give-feedback/305974#comment247007_305974

Comment: [**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) - from the help center page on the editing privilege. Editing any one part of a post and leaving the rest of the problems is not a useful edit, approving an edit that does this does not help the site as it does not teach this simple rule. If the user does not edit at least most of the problems with the post, you should not approve it.

Comment: I'm NOT approving it, I am improving it. I don't want to reject and edit because then I have to do all the edits they picked up as well as the ones they didn't. That's the point, I want to be able to finish off the job but also let the person know to do a more complete job. I might add, when I look at the edit history, other reviewers have simply approved these, even where blatant errors were ignored. I have a separate feature suggestion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311331/edit-review-votes-could-be-changed-to-3-approve-and-2-reject to try and reduce the trivial approvals

Comment: If you are choosing "Improve Edit" then you *are* approving the edit. The user gets a +2 as if the edit had otherwise been approved. Furthermore, if you chose to Reject and Edit, it actually provides the user with a helpful message if they check their edit suggestion history: *`"This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed."`* So, if the edit did not correct critical issues with the post ("*blatant errors were ignored*"), you should use Reject and Edit instead of Improve Edit.

Comment: @Drew: _"with enough rank, shouldn't I be able to go to your profile page and send a direct message"_ -- one of the things I like a _lot_ about Stack Overflow is that it avoids a lot of the usual Internet bickering that occurs elsewhere. I believe that to a large extent this is a result of the tightly-restricted messaging paradigm here. Non-public messages to a specific user are just inviting the less-mature and unprofessional out there to abuse the system. And personalized messages can have a greater emotional impact on the recipient than other abuses (like serial voting).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am sure abuse happens everywhere, like a lot of what I see under posts by people perhaps throwing down a few highballs and wailing on people

Comment: @Drew: a major difference is that truly abusive comments are often never even seen by their intended target. Since comments are public, they are moderated by the community before they can do harm. Whether it's due to that effect, or just that people behave better Stack Overflow, fact is the prevalence of comments that are genuinely abusive is remarkably low on Stack Overflow as compared to other Internet forums/sites/media/etc.

Comment: then a comment that could hang off an edit attempt, like "Please correct more than extremely minor fixes in the face of all else you could have cleaned up here". And the message is received. If it is abused, then the right gets taken away or the acct gets handled as it always does for the poster of comments. But this will not be implemented, because the current workflow is conveyor belt and good enough. Instead, we have a locked in inability to do much of anything. It is what it is.

Comment: @Drew the trouble I see with that is that it will be likely several people feel obliged / the need to do that at the same time, resulting in piling up on someone. Besides that, its basically dishing out instructions directly to someone's face; the massive ignore you will receive will be more frustrating than the incomplete edits. In the end, a bag is going to be punched at the gym - better go there directly :)

Comment: @Gimby, none of these changes to the system have a chance of happening as I see it. I might find them useful, but I certainly don't anticipate anything.

Answer (score 12):

Let's consider the scenarios:

- Edit is good: **Approve**.
- Edit is halfway, but close to good: **Improve Edit**.
- Edit is halfway, but close to  rubbish: **Reject and Edit** (or **Reject**, if you are not in the mood).
- Edit is rubbish: **Reject** (or **Reject and Edit**, if you are in the mood).
- You don't have the expertise to determine the quality of the edit: **Skip**

[image]

If you want to educate the user, why not educate everyone else as well with a public comment? If they get irritated by a polite (or not) public comment about a mistake they did, the Internet is probably not for them.

Comment: IIRC they can only receive pings on a post if the edit is applied. In cases where the edit is rejected you can create a chatroom and invite the user.

Comment: @TinyGiant: according to the Help Center, you are correct: [_"You can only `@reply` to users who have already left a comment, or edited the post"_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). That said, a user who is interested in edit feedback can check their own "Reviews" activity and find comments related to rejected reviews. Maybe rather than allowing comments directed to the user specifically, it would be better if a user's inbox received notifications of rejected reviews.

Comment: It sounds like OP wants a "Reject and improve" option so they can formerly knock-back the (possibly robo) editor for doing an incomplete job, _but_ leverage the [correct but incomplete] changes they did make (see [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295150/2096401).

Comment: So what do we do to notify users whos edit we reject? Just rejecting with a custom comment will not cause a notification (if I understand things right), and chanses are that the user will never see it. Those who rutinely check their review histories are probably not the users we need to educate.